# Custom traceback function for matrix not working

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

I am trying to implement the Nussinov algorithm for RNA folding in Python 3.

So far, I have my correct matrix and I am trying to `traceback` through this matrix.

Essentially, the function should start at the top right cell of a matrix and proceed through the cells according to the algorithm, until it reaches the diagonal.

The problem is nothing happens to change the `structure` list.
Can anyone tell me why?

```
structure = list()

for base in seq:
    structure.append('.')

def traceback(i, j, matrix1):
    if j - i > 0:
       return

    elif matrix1[i][j] == matrix1[i+1][j]: # if value same as cell under i,j
        traceback(i+1, j, matrix1)

    elif matrix1[i][j] == matrix1[i][j-1]: # if value same as cell on left of i,j
        traceback(i, j-1, matrix1)

    elif matrix1[i][j] == (matrix1[i+1][j-1] + 1):
        traceback(i+1, j-1, matrix1)
        structure[i] = '('
        structure[j] = ')'

print(matrix1)
traceback(0, n-1, matrix1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing will ever happen with your matrix because your first if-check will always perform an early return:

```
def traceback(i, j, matrix1):
    if j - i > 0:
        return
    ...

traceback(0, n-1, matrix1)
```

To go beyond the first return, `j` should be less than `i`, right? Now observe your inputs:

```
   (n - 1) - 0 <= 0
=> n - 1 <= 0
=> n <= 1
```

So in the current state, your `traceback` function will execute the matrix element checks if and only if `n == 0` or `n == 1`, both being the trivial cases of an empty submatrix or a scalar submatrix.

I suppose the first block should restrict the traversal to the upper triangle, above the main diagonal? Then simply flip the sign:

```
if j - i < 0:
    return
```

Comment: Thank you :) actually it's there to restrict traversion to the lower triangle, below the diagonal!

Comment: Oh, then your start element does not fit - `(0, n - 1)` is the right most one. Maybe you meant to start at `(n - 1, 0)` instead? It would be the one in the lower left corner.

Comment: And there you have your contradiction as I described it in the answer - you start at a position that is forbidden by your `traceback` logic.

Comment: I see the logic. Thanks so much for the help!